# how to write customizesd output file format in mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

Please suggest to me how to update the output fileformat (part-r-00000)(default file format) to another file format like csv or txt file formatsin map reduce programs.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: yes, i tried but no use. :( <br> i need this for report generation

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
hdfs dfs -cat /path/in/hdfs/part* |hdfs dfs -put - /chosen/path/in/hdfs/name_of_file.txt
```

OR

```
hdfs dfs -cat /path/in/hdfs/part* |hdfs dfs -put - chosen/path/in/hdfs/name_of_file.csv
```

Another method is `-getmerge` which copies to local but then you need to `-copyFromLocal` back to `hdfs` but it serves the purpose of changing your file format:

```
hdfs dfs -getmerge /path/in/hdfs/part* /path/in/local/file_name.format

hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /path/in/local/file_name.format /path/in/hdfs/archive/
```

Answer (score -1):

one way is you can copy the part-r-00000 file to xyz.txt file by using put command of hadoop.
like hdfs dfs -put part-r-00000 to xyz.txt

Comment: thanks Mahesh. Actually, i want to save the output file like <Filename>.fileformat.

Comment: Actually, i want to save the output file like <Filename>.fileformat. is there way to update output file format.